# convert oracle sql query to mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

how do i convert this oracle sql  to mysql?

```
SELECT b.BHG_SUSUN, c.DISASTER_TYPE , b.NAMA_BAHAGIAN , c.CASE_ID, 
       c.REPORTED_DATE, c.INCIDENT_DATE, c.ADDRESS, c.NO_FAMILY_AFFECTED, c.NO_PERSON_AFFECTED,
       pe.JUMLAH_AIR_GELEN, pe.JUMLAH_AIR_LITER, pe.JUMLAH_AIR, pe.UNIT_UKURAN, 
       (NVL(pe.KOS_AIR,0) + NVL(pe.KOS_PENGANGKUTAN,0)) JUMLAH_BANTUAN,
       pe.CATATAN
FROM T_DRAM_CASE c, T_DRAM_BORANG_PESANAN_AIR pe, T_CCS_BAHAGIAN b    
WHERE c.CASE_ID = pe.CASE_ID (+)   
AND lower(c.DISASTER_TYPE) like '%kemarau'  
AND c.DIVISION = b.BAHAGIAN_ID
AND c.DIVISION LIKE '2'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.  Have you tried to rewrite yourself into MySQL?

Comment: yes i have. i know that NVL need to be changed to IFNULL and the left join need to be writen into FROM T_DRAM_CASE c LEFT JOIN T_DRAM_BORANG_PESANAN_AIR pe ON c.CASE_ID= pe.CASE_ID . but then where should i put the third table (T_CCS_BAHAGIAN b)?

Comment: @steph, so you have the idea, but you still ask this in SO?

Comment: yes i have the idea. but im stuck halfway. like i only know how to convert upper part of the code only

Comment: Please update your question to show what you've tried so far and exactly the part you need help with

Comment: the question is solved already. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this below script-

```
SELECT
    b.BHG_SUSUN, c.DISASTER_TYPE , b.NAMA_BAHAGIAN , c.CASE_ID, 
   c.REPORTED_DATE, c.INCIDENT_DATE, c.ADDRESS, c.NO_FAMILY_AFFECTED, c.NO_PERSON_AFFECTED,
   pe.JUMLAH_AIR_GELEN, pe.JUMLAH_AIR_LITER, pe.JUMLAH_AIR, pe.UNIT_UKURAN,
    coalesce(pe.KOS_AIR,0) + coalesce(pe.KOS_PENGANGKUTAN,0) JUMLAH_BANTUAN,
    pe.CATATAN
FROM T_DRAM_CASE c
INNER JOIN T_DRAM_BORANG_PESANAN_AIR pe ON c.CASE_ID = pe.CASE_ID
INNER JOIN T_CCS_BAHAGIAN b ON c.DIVISION = b.BAHAGIAN_ID   
WHERE lower(c.DISASTER_TYPE) like '%kemarau'  
AND c.DIVISION LIKE '%2%';
```

Comment: may i know why the left join is changed to inner join? i dont really understand

Comment: There were no JOINs defined your query. I just used INNER JOIN. But you can replace as per your requirement :)

Comment: thanks its working. i changed the first inner join to left join.

Comment: @mkRabbani the original `where` clause with the comma joins has `c.CASE_ID = pe.CASE_ID (+) `, hence the left join.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamRobertson for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is:

```
SELECT b.BHG_SUSUN, c.DISASTER_TYPE , b.NAMA_BAHAGIAN , c.CASE_ID, 
       c.REPORTED_DATE, c.INCIDENT_DATE, c.ADDRESS, c.NO_FAMILY_AFFECTED, c.NO_PERSON_AFFECTED,
       pe.JUMLAH_AIR_GELEN, pe.JUMLAH_AIR_LITER, pe.JUMLAH_AIR, pe.UNIT_UKURAN, 
       (COALESCE(pe.KOS_AIR, 0) + COALESCE(pe.KOS_PENGANGKUTAN,0)) as JUMLAH_BANTUAN,
       pe.CATATAN
FROM T_DRAM_CASE c JOIN
     T_CCS_BAHAGIAN b
     ON c.DIVISION = b.BAHAGIAN_ID LEFT JOIN
     T_DRAM_BORANG_PESANAN_AIR pe     
     ON c.CASE_ID = pe.CASE_ID 
WHERE LOWER(c.DISASTER_TYPE) like '%kemarau' AND
      c.DIVISION = '2';  -- `LIKE` is unnecessary here
```

Note that you can probably express the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE c.DISASTER_TYPE like '%kemarau' AND
      c.DIVISION = 2;  -- assuming `DIVISION` is a number
```

Because:

- MySQL does `case`-insensitive comparisons;
- `LIKE` is unnecessary.